# How to login to newly installed Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, login, vmware

I have just installed Ubuntu on a VmWare virtual machine.

IT wants me to login to finish installation, but I do not remember ever creating an account, so I have no idea how to login!

I have tried user ubuntu with no password (and various passwords for root).

Comment: There is no default login.  If it is asking for a login, then you created one earlier.  Do you remember it asking you for your information?  It asks for full name, and suggests a login name, then asks for a password.

Comment: Do did you do the VMvare automated install? VMware askss for the password before actual installation and automates the process

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password should help you.